# form of a condition function using leftbrace

Tags: braces

In fact I want to write this function definition with the leftbrace :
[image]

And here is the code that I have written:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Si \,\,\,\,\,\, \varepsilon Q_s \geq \Delta Q_s\\
Si \,\,\,\,\,\,  \varepsilon Q_s \leq -\Delta Q_s\\
Si \,\,\,\,\,\,  \varepsilon P_s \geq \Delta P_s\\
Si \,\,\,\,\,\,  -\Delta P_s \leq \varepsilon P_s \leq \Delta P_s\\
Si \,\,\,\,\,\,  \varepsilon P_s \leq -\Delta P_s
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `cases` and `alignedat`. Since you seem to write in French, I took the liberty to use the French inequality signs. I propose also a second alignment which looks lighter, in my opinion:
    \documentclass[9pt]{extbook}

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\def\fgeq{\geqslant}
\def\fleq{\geqslant}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 &\text{Si} & \enspace & \varepsilon Q_s \fgeq \Delta Q_s & \quad\implies & H_Q = 1\\
 & \text{Si} & & \varepsilon Q_s \fleq -\Delta Q_s & \implies & H_Q = -1\\
 & \text{Si} & & \varepsilon P_s \fgeq \Delta P_s & \implies & H_P = 1\\
 & \text{Si} & & -\Delta P_s \fleq \varepsilon P_s \fleq \Delta P_s & \implies & H_P = 0\\
 & \text{Si} & & \varepsilon P_s \fleq -\Delta P_s & \implies & H_P = -1
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A single `cases` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) is all you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\text{Si } \varepsilon Q_s \geq \Delta Q_s   & \Rightarrow H_Q=\phantom{-}1 \\
\text{Si } \varepsilon Q_s \leq -\Delta Q_s  & \Rightarrow H_Q=-1  \\
\text{Si } \varepsilon P_s \geq \Delta P_s   & \Rightarrow H_P=\phantom{-}1 \\
\text{Si }{-}\Delta P_s\leq\varepsilon P_s\leq\Delta P_s 
                                             & \Rightarrow H_P=\phantom{-}0\\
\text{Si } \varepsilon P_s \leq -\Delta P_s  & \Rightarrow H_P=-1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```